# Ambiguous code in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select DocNo From thecat24 a inner join Thecat23 x 
on a.N_Solicitud = x.N_Solicitud where x.Codigo_Proyecto = N'2' and DocNo <> 33
```

It says DocNo is ambiguous and i cant see why? Any fix?

Comment: change DocNo to a.DocNo and you should be through

Comment: if it exists in both tables it is surely ambiguous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly because `DocNo` is in both tables.  When you have multiple tables in a query, you should qualify *all* column names.  This is just a good habit, so your queries are maintainable, readable, and unambiguous.

Something like this:

```
Select a.DocNo
From thecat24 a inner join
     Thecat23 x
    on a.N_Solicitud = x.N_Solicitud
where x.Codigo_Proyecto = N'2' and a.DocNo <> 33;
```

Answer (score 2):

Cause most probably both the joined table has the same column name and thus you need to refer it with the table alias like

```
Select a.DocNo...
```

(OR)

```
Select x.DocNo...
```